# Android - Activity with YouTubePlayerFragment blank and unresponsive

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am trying to build sample Android app in which the main activity contains several fragments, including a YouTubePlayerFragment.  I get no errors with my implementation, but when I run the app in an emulator or on my phone, the main activity is completely blank and unresponsive.  The app works fine if I remove the fragment containing the YouTube player.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

**YouTubeFragment.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;

public class YouTubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static YouTubeFragment newInstance() {
        YouTubeFragment fragment = new YouTubeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    private void init(){
        initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    public YouTubeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_you_tube, container, false);

        YouTubeFragment ytf = newInstance();
        ytf.init();
        //inside fragment use getFragmentManager instead of getFragmentSupportManager
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.youTubePlayer, ytf)
                .commit();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

**fragement_you_tube.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="androidsample.example.com.fragments1.YouTubeFragment"
>

  <FrameLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/youTubePlayer">
  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="androidsample.example.com.fragments1.Frag2"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="androidsample.example.com.fragments1.Frag1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="androidsample.example.com.fragments1.YouTubeFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help, I have a working version of this (problems with target SDK 21, using 19):

**YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments2;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;


public class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            String errorMessage = "custom ERror MessAgE";
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.youtube_fragment);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package androidsample.example.com.fragments2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```